# MSSQL tools on Ubuntu (20.10) Docker Image on M1 MacBook

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu, apple-m1

on my M1 MacbookPro I have created a Dockerfile below:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.10

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg2

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN exit
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN source ~/.bashrc
```

It uses the Ubuntu `20.10` image, and attempts to install [Microsoft's ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). I have followed the commands as per [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17).

When I run a build, I get an error `Unable to locate package msodbcsql17`. I have tried running and SSHing into the container and I still get the same error.

```
% docker build .           
[+] Building 5.3s (11/14)                                                                                                                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                    0.4s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                       0.5s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.10                                                                                                                         2.8s
 => [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.10@sha256:6b603b0f3b8fc71b1a97bd38e081e8df04793f1447362c12385b48106aaded3f                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/11] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/11] RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg2                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/11] RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/11] RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/11] RUN exit                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/11] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [ 8/11] RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17                                                                                                                      1.8s
------                                                                                                                                                                                       
 > [ 8/11] RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17:                                                                                                                                 
#11 0.893 Reading package lists...                                                                                                                                                           
#11 1.278 Building dependency tree...                                                                                                                                                        
#11 1.347 Reading state information...
#11 1.394 E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql17
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17]: exit code: 100
```

Comment: I think you need to run `apt-get update` first and it should do the trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67618911/laravel-sail-docker-unable-to-locate-package-msodbcsql17

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue to the one above and found that the problem was due to there being no msodbcsql17 package available for arm64 architecture(M1 Mac). The solution was to change the base image at the start of the docker file to

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8.6
```

Or in your case

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:20.10
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error[Unable to locate package msodbcsql17
]
Find the following link.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/6494

Comment: would you please add more explain instead of just posting the link